# Como formatar o date no firefox

Tags: javascript, html5, firefox

Eu estava fazendo uma página web e precisava de um `textarea` para a data. Quando coloquei o input com o type date no Chrome ele cria uma máscara para a data, não permitindo que os usuários digitem letras e não precisem digitar os `/` para separar a data. Porém no Mozilla Firefox não faz isso, fica um textarea normal.

Eu queria saber se tem como formatar esse textarea da mesma forma que o do Chrome ou parecido, pelo menos fazer as funções de não permitir digitar número e separar a data com os `/` automaticamente? E se tiver, como seria isso?

Comment: Pode usar algum [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms-individual-input-types), o suporte do campo de data pode ser visto [aqui](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panchester, você pode fazer um modulo com uma feature detection (no caso, para verificar se o browser da suporte ao `input[type='date']`).

```js
var DatePicker = (function () {
  var DatePicker = function (element) {
    var that = this;
    if (element instanceof jQuery) {
      this.element = element[0];
      this.wrapper = element;
    } else {
      this.element = element;
      this.wrapper = $(this.element);
    }

    if (this.isNative)
      return;

    this.element.type = "text";
    this.wrapper.datetimepicker({
      timepicker: false,
      mask: true,
      format: 'd/m/Y',
      onChangeDateTime: function (data, input) {
        var event = new Event("input");
        that.element.dispatchEvent(event);
      }
    });
    
    
    Object.defineProperty(this.element, "valueAsDate", {
      get: function () {
        return that.wrapper.datetimepicker("getValue");
      },
      set: function (value) {
        that.wrapper.datetimepicker({ value: value });
      }
    })
  }

  var input = document.createElement("input");
  Object.defineProperty(DatePicker.prototype, "isNative", {
    writerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: "valueAsDate" in input
  })

  return DatePicker;
})();

var element = document.getElementById("data");
var datePicker = new DatePicker(element);

element.valueAsDate = new Date(2012, 10, 2);
element.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  console.log(element.valueAsDate);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<input id="data" type="date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

O firefox não oferece suporte pro `date` ainda, o ideal seria você usar uma biblioteca javascript para facilitar pro usuário, eu recomendo o datepicker do jqueryui:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Mas caso você só queira fazer uma máscara pro usuário digitar uma data corretamente, você pode usar o jquery mask:

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/